# android dialog set icon to title

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have this dialog class and i want to set icon to its title:

```
public class DialogMealInformation extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    private TextView tv_information;
    private Button b_ok;
    private String information;

    public DialogMealInformation(Context context, String information) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.information = information;
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_meal_information);
        getWindow().setLayout(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        setTitle("Info !");

        initialize();
    }
```

it tried like this:

```
setTitle(R.layout.dialog_simple_header);
```

#### dialog_simple_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_dialog_simple_header_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_information"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/more_information" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but the title after that was "res/layout/dialog_simple_header.x" just text, no icon is appear, why please , what is the solution , thanks alot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

follow this on any `button` click or on your `onActivity` or any place you want this dialog to show. do read my comments every after `//`

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("TITLE"); // your dialog title 
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your message"); // a message above the buttons
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home); // the icon besides the title you have to change it to the icon/image you have. 
            alertDialog.setButton("Got IT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // here you can add a method  to the button clicked. you can create another button just by copying alertDialog.setButton("okay")
                }

            });
alertDialog.show();
```

---

do me a favor and delete this

```
    public DialogMealInformation(Context context, String information) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.information = information;
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_meal_information);
    getWindow().setLayout(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    setTitle("Info !");

    initialize();
}
```

and add mine instead !

Answer (score 3):

here is a dialog with custom theme and View

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout_third);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

here i'm setting the theme to transparent and then i'm using `dialog.SetContentView` to add the layout. in my layout i'm using only an `imageview` and here is my layout for the dialog.

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/onetimeedit"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:src="@drawable/drag" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

you can then add `textView` as Title  just add it to the layout. and or using `dialog.setTitle("MyTitleShouldByHere");`

hope my example clear it for you, and if that what you want please do accept the answer so other people can get it easy. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dialog.setTitle(int resId) is used if you wish to set the title text to a string resource.

What you are looking for is what you are already doing - setContentView. In your custom xml there make the title look like what you prefer, or - if you wish to set it at runtime, just get a reference to the ImageView and set it in code.

Hope this helps.